# Typing a partial record where any present key must be defined

Tags: typescript

How could one type a record/object where the properties are optional, but if they are present they must be defined?

For example:

```
type K = "foo" | "bar";

type R = {
    // The props are optional, great, but I don't want to allow undefined values
    [T in K]?: number;
};

const r1: R = { foo: 1 }; // Ok, great
const r2: R = { foo: undefined }; // I want this to be an error

// Error: Type '(number | undefined)[]' is not assignable to type 'number[]'
// I want this to be ok, as all present keys should be defined
const values: number[] = Object.values(r1);
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA0lC8UBEAzA9mpUA+yBGAhgE5IDcAsAFBWiRQBKCUA3lVO1APSdQAqAFtDBE0YAM5Ri0UcACWaAHYEANgBooAcyIQCwdXgCuwKAEkoAE0UByYwHcCC48DSTlytLagGF5iClkKEOZQAG4qBhBibBwA2rxQAbAAugD8AFxQCgYAtngQRBSUAL6FVADGimLGRACMGYyIzFDoaBk1UCVcPADyANbqWjrA5ZXVAEz1TE0tGd6+-oHBndymUPaOUMD8shLOUHmSClD5IkRUVCsAokSnGbzg0FYAFFm5+ThePn4BQQCUMUkrAkJAo0MYCGIxLINEo8MpoHtaI9XnkiACrBceGZ1k5trsXAc0P1JBIVMooMJIhANr0ICAJGJ+GgDMpggd5j9zCMFFVQuFIhkUfkAUxungAFYQMrAAB0YWUETET1qv1IQA)

After using such typing I want to be able use `Object.values()` and not have to deal with any `undefined` types, only `number` in the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TypeScript 4.4:**

This is made possible with and implemented in [this PR](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/43947) released in TypeScript 4.4!

Compile the example with [`--exactOptionalPropertyTypes`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#exactOptionalPropertyTypes) to get the desired behavior, no other changes needed!

In `--exactOptionalPropertyTypes` mode for an optional property to also be assignable `undefined` it needs to be typed with `undefined`. For example: `{ porp?: number | undefined }`.

An example from the `--exactOptionalPropertyTypes` PR:

```
// Compile in --strictOptionalProperties mode
function f2(obj: { a?: string }) {
    obj = obj;
    obj.a = obj.a;  // Error,  'string | undefined' not assignable to 'string'
    if ('a' in obj) {
        obj.a = obj.a;  // Ok
    }
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty('a')) {
        obj.a = obj.a;  // Ok
    }
}
```

---

**TypeScript <=4.3:**

[andrewbranch](https://github.com/andrewbranch) of TypeScript [commented in Jan 2021](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/41921#issuecomment-759644748):

> [...] there’s no way to say that some property must be either string or not present on the object at all.
> (You can do that for fresh object literals via a union type, but can easily get around it by indirect assignment.)

And there is still an open [issue on "Distinguish missing and undefined"](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13195) from 2016.

So it seems there is unfortunately no way to do this in TypeScript, in a general way anyway, at the moment.

Comment: Note: `strictOptionalProperties` has been renamed to `exactOptionalPropertyTypes` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67729412/typing-a-partial-record-where-any-present-key-must-be-defined